# Elementor page skew issue

Tags: wordpress, elementor

[image]

[image]

My Phlox theme with Elementor has all of a sudden scrambled! It looks normal in the editor and then live or preview it is all skewed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is to do with the page template. The particular rates section I have built using ultimate addons looks fine with WP default template but terrible with an elementor template. This has only just happened.

Comment: Have you installed Classic Editor plugin?

Comment: DO you mean the WordPress gutenburg editor? If so, yes this was automatically installed. How can you get rid of it? Thanks. I have fixed it now, the page kept reverting back to default template frustratingly.

Comment: Install [Classic Editor Addon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor-addon/). Plugin installs Classic Editor and removes settings for users to use Gutenberg.

Comment: Thank you. Do people like the new editor?

Comment: Most [Gutenberg Reviews](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/gutenberg/reviews/) are one star. I have Gutenberg on a test site. It is difficult to learn. It should be a plugin.